# MS SQL Connection in java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, netbeans-7

How do we connect to MS SQL 2008 server win jdk 1.6?

When I connect it via netbeans

```
url = jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.4:1434;databaseName=pollbooth
```

or

```
url = jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.4:1434/pollbooth
```

when ever I already properly configure MS SQl driver, sqljdbc.jar & sqljdbc4.jar, it sends

```
can't establish a connection to given url using 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver(JRE).
```

Comment: try to "telnet" to the DB server and see if its working

Comment: I connecting in netbeans so there is no requirement of code. netbeans want only driver jar & database connection url with username & password

Comment: Is your database definitely configured to allow TCP/IP access?

Comment: yes this databse is connected with .net via tcp / ip. but in java i'm unable to connect.

Comment: May i know whether the sqljdbc4.jar is in the driver folder?

Comment: in my project lib folder

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help you in connecting to the MSSQL Server database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx